# How to settargetpath twice in application(Program Application and Data Directory)

Tags: wix, wix3

I am unable to set target path for second time.

In my application for custom installation I want to give user flexibility to browse and set target path for Application install location and Application Data Directory.

1) I am able to set target path for install location of the application.

2) But, I am unable to set target path for Application Data Folder Selection.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating your own UI sequence. The easiest way is to start from one of the predefined sequences in the [WIX sources](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.2519.0/wix35-sources.zip) (like `WixUI_InstallDir.wxs`) and insert your own dialog.

For more details, see [Adding and Customizing Dialogs in WiX 3](http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/).

Comment: Thanks for your rply. I tried using WixUI_InstallDir.wxs and i was able to use the browseDlg to set my Installation Path. but Problem arises when i want to use BrowseDLg next Time to set the AppDataFolder Path for My Applications working Directory.My problem is i am not able to use the setTargePath Event to set the directory path for my WORKDIR folder. I tried Searching this on Internet but no proper answer to this was available. Please share your expertise on this . thanks in advance ..